# Can you predict the path of a particle headed for 2 slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the Double Slit experiment, particles are shot at 2 slits. We know that the particles will show a striped pattern on the screen if unobserved, but show up directly behind the slits if observed. I want to ask if it is possible to predict the path of the particle by controlling how it is shot. Is this counted as an observation? Or is it fundamentally impossible to control the particle's path to that extent?

Comment: In predicting the path, you are assuming a theory, as well as it takes a path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum mechanics says that there is no "path" of any particle. To go from one point to other light or particles travel through all possible ways and each way has an associated probability amplitude with it. If you try to measure the path you will find any one of these infinite ways. Of course the path with the most probability will occur mostly. But when you do this experiment you actually force the particle to choose between any one of those infinite paths. Thus the quantum nature of its movement("Quantum Superposition") vanishes and the wave function collapses to a single state.

Answer (score 0):

In standard QM, there is no path in the usual sense.

In Bohmian Mechanics (actually a recovery of a proposal by de Broglie) there are paths; and these are smooth; there are also interpretations in which the paths are random walks.

Comment: But even if you choose an interpretation with paths you can't select a group of paths that aim at just one slit and still get interference fringes from repeated trials.

Comment: @timaeus: I'm not clear on the details; and it does look unlikely on the face if it; but Bohmian Mechanics has a pilot wave which directs the paths - it's supposed to match the actual physical predictions of standard QM.

Comment: I'm very familiar with pilot wave theories and de Broglie Bohm in particular. But there is no way to get the interference pattern and also only have paths that go through just one slit. The possible paths fill the entire wave, and to get the interference you have to have a wave with possible trajectories going through both slits. There isn't any room for disagreement. Regular quantum mechanics says the same thing: the wave needs a non zero probability current through both slits to get interference fringes.

Comment: @timaeus: it's the wave that guides the particle; that wave follows Schrodingers equation; it's seems eminently a possibility.

Comment: *Of course* the wave guides the particle, that is **why** it is called a pilot wave theory. But that does not change the fact that the wave interference only happens when there is a current through both slits and that when there is a current through both slits then the unknown initial position which can be anywhere in the wave, leads to the ability to take a trajectory through either slit as the wave goes through both. And the only way to force the path through just one slit is to force the whole wave through just one, and thus kill the fringes. This isn't confusing.

Comment: @timaeus: the wave interference happens at the level of the wave, that's  **why** it's called a wave - waves **interfere** - I don't see why you're finding this confusing; nor why you're introducing unknown initial positions.

Comment: I don't know why you keep saying things I already know while insinuating (wrongly) that you could direct a series of paths through just one slit and get still see an interference pattern you can't. You could post select such a population but that has the opposite causality as directing. You are the one that brought up paths from Bohemian Mechanics. And that theory isn't unclear and doesn't leave any possibility for a series of paths forced to go through just one slit and still getting an interference pattern. So I'll repeat it very slowly so you can't misunderstand ...

Comment: Step one, interference fringes happen from a build up of how many land on different regions when you repeat the experiment. So we will have to repeat the experiment to see if the fringes are there. Step two we are asked to direct the path so that it goes through just one slit, i.e. we choose one of the slits and make sure the wave guides the particle path to go through the slit we selected. So we choose one slit and then repeat the experiment. Third step we can't control the initial position, only the wave. And together the initial position and the wave determine the path in Bohemian Mechanics

Comment: Now since we can't control the initial position except that it b where the wave in nonzero the one way to direct the path through the slit of our choice is to send the whole wave through the slit in which case we know regular quantum mechanics predicts no interference fringes so we also get no interference fringes. And conversely if we send the wave through both then you can trace the paths through both and find they start at initial conditions we couldn't control so some one them will go through each slit, thus we failed to make it go through just the one we selected.

Comment: This isn't the place for extended discussion - I see the door to chat has opened; I'll add just one extra thing; sure, *I* brought up Bohmian Mechanics; and this because the question asked whether '**paths** can be **predicted**'; and my answer is in terms of the situation posited or implied by the question. This shouldn't need saying: but it is a field of **active research**. Let's leave it there - no point clogging up comments and wasting both our time.